# Difference between is_int and modulus%1?

Tags: php

I ran the following code, to test if a number was divisible by 7 and then return only if true.

is_int gives me what I think, but using modulus to check if it is an integer (%1) I get floats too.

```
for ($i = 100; $i < 222; $i++) {
        $dividedBy7 = $i/7;
        if(is_int($dividedBy7)){
            echo 'is int thinks '.$dividedBy7.'</br>';
        }
        if($dividedBy7 % 1 == 0){
            echo 'modulus thinks '.$dividedBy7.'</br>';
        }
}
```

OUTPUT

modulus thinks 14.2857142857, modulus thinks 14.4285714286 etc

is int thinks15, 16 etc

What is wrong with my understanding of modulus?

EDIT
I appreciate that %7 is the correct use of modulus in this example, but this is a simplification of the situation.

Comment: Use modulus operation, it's integer and the proper way. So, `if($i % 7 == 0)` then it's dividable by 7

Comment: And what's the difference? Validate it via proper way to check if it's dividable by 7 (so, with % operator)

Comment: `$variable % 1 == 0` is as saying _if $variable divided by 1 has remaining of 0_ and that's always the case.

Comment: @dexa, so (3.14 % 1 == 0) ?

Comment: @Gamemorize yes [codepad](http://codepad.org/bWgUiWhq)

Comment: @dexa, as I said in my question, the problem is certainly mine! Why is %1 always zero?

Comment: % is for int, if you want remaining to be float you may use [fmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php), example [codepad](http://codepad.org/Z7AIzFZD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question: modulus operator (so, `%`) is an **integer** operator. Thus, it expects operands to be integer. If not, it will convert them to integer. That stands from [implementation](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/Zend/zend_operators.c#1025):

```
ZEND_API int mod_function(zval *result, zval *op1, zval *op2 TSRMLS_DC) /* {{{ */
{
    zval op1_copy, op2_copy;
    long op1_lval;

    zendi_convert_to_long(op1, op1_copy, result);
    op1_lval = Z_LVAL_P(op1);
    zendi_convert_to_long(op2, op2_copy, result);

    if (Z_LVAL_P(op2) == 0) {
        zend_error(E_WARNING, "Division by zero");
        ZVAL_BOOL(result, 0);
        return FAILURE;         /* modulus by zero */
    }

    if (Z_LVAL_P(op2) == -1) {
        /* Prevent overflow error/crash if op1==LONG_MIN */
        ZVAL_LONG(result, 0);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    ZVAL_LONG(result, op1_lval % Z_LVAL_P(op2));
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

So as you can see,

```
    zendi_convert_to_long(op1, op1_copy, result);
    op1_lval = Z_LVAL_P(op1);
    zendi_convert_to_long(op2, op2_copy, result);
```

will produce the conversion. That's why it's:

```
var_dump(14.4 % 7); //int(0) since (int)14.4 is 14 which is dividable by 7
```

**Proper way** would be to check the reminder from division by 7, thus,

```
if($i % 7 == 0)
{
   //$i is dividable by 7
}
```

Use integer operators with integer operands to avoid any unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks Alma Do! I have to admit the first part is a bit over my head but the final functioning of % makes sense. Php is almost being too loose, it 'should' throw a type error!

Answer (score 0):

The [is_int()](http://php.net/is_int) function (as all its `is_...` counterparts) is about the PHP variable **type**.

Certainly, PHP will not perform unnecessary casting:

```
var_dump(80/7, 70/7);
```

```
float(11.428571428571)
int(10)
```

... but this also works the other way:

```
var_dump(70/7, 70.0/7);
```

```
int(10)
float(10)
```

To sum up: it's just a hack, not particularly robust or useful, and will lead to interesting maintenance issues.